# PHP Mail containing Images from a Directory

Tags: php

Trying to have a PHP script send an email that contains two images that the user is pre-selecting from a previous page (out of a select element).  I'm not quite sure how to accomplish the image attachment.  Here is my code, not working obviously, please let me know if my logic is right or if I'm way off here.

```
<?php

$to=$_POST["email"];

$bannerimg=$_POST["banimg"];

$adimage=$_POST["adimage"];

$bannerimageshow=echo "<img src=imgdir/$bannerimg>"."<br /><br />";
$adimageshow=echo "<img src=addir/$adimage>"."<br /><br />";

echo $bannerimageshow;
echo $adimageshow;

/*
$subject=$_POST["subject"];

$message=$_POST["message"];

$from="mailface@mailface.com";

$headers=array();
$headers[]="MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[]="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[]="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
$headers[]="From: ".$from;

$advertised=mail($to,$bannerimageshow,$adimageshow,$subject,$message,join("\n",$headers));

if ($advertised){
echo "Working";
}

*/

?>
```

My echo statements are not returning anything.  Any and all help is appreciated :)

Thanks in advance.

Dustin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` has no return value.

Instead of

```
$bannerimageshow=echo "<img src=imgdir/$bannerimg>"."<br /><br />";
```

just use

```
$bannerimageshow="<img src=imgdir/$bannerimg>"."<br /><br />";
```

or, even simpler,

```
$bannerimageshow="<img src=imgdir/$bannerimg><br /><br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your echo statements aren't working because you've commented them out.

```
<?php

$to=$_POST["email"];

$bannerimg=$_POST["banimg"];

$adimage=$_POST["adimage"];

$bannerimageshow=echo "<img src=imgdir/$bannerimg>"."<br /><br />";
$adimageshow=echo "<img src=addir/$adimage>"."<br /><br />";

echo $bannerimageshow;
echo $adimageshow;

$subject=$_POST["subject"];

$message=$_POST["message"];

$from="mailface@mailface.com";

$headers=array();
$headers[]="MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[]="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[]="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
$headers[]="From: ".$from;

$advertised=mail($to,$bannerimageshow,$adimageshow,$subject,$message,join("\n",$headers));

if ($advertised){
echo "Working";
}


?>
```

Comment: Thanks Poly, however, the echo statements I was referring to were $bannerimageshow and $adimageshow, which were above the commented sections.  In any case, removing the comments altogether does not alter the outcome.